# How do I set the background color of my dashboard that include pivot tables also?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I selected the whole worksheet and set the fill color value as yellow, removed the grid lines and expected the extended rows to have the yellow color, but it becomes white when the rows are collapsed.
check the pictures[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this task with Conditional Formatting. Select area around your PivotTable, then insert `ConditionalFormatting`=>`HighlightCellsRules`=>`Equal to`=0 (Select custom formatting and choose yellow color of background).

Comment: That's useful!
Thank.

Comment: You are welcome! could you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1):

But.... unfortunately, this will not work if your pivot area changes sizes depending on the data, it will also fill the areas INSIDE of the pivot table that do not contain data...

You will have to do right click the pivot table
Pivot Table > PivotTable Tools > Options > Options > Layout & Format > Format > For empty cells show: -

Upon further investigation, I have to correct myself... Even that does not do it..

It looks as if Excel is deleting the cells including the formating when it collapses. I set the pivot table condition so it had no data (only headers) Then set conditional formating for the rows below. -> looks good.

Expand pivot table with data and then collapse it again.

-> rules for the same cells are gone...

There probably is a VBA way to get the area of the pivot table and then paint around it, then you need the resize event... the usual rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and like @I0sens noted the Conditional Formatting wouldn't work. I went ahead and did this using VBA.

Essentially check a range if null then fill. If your column or row count is usually stable ranges may be best but if it's all over I would recommend doing by cell.

This is just a quick sample:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("K27:K31")) = 0 Then
         Range("K27:K31").Interior.Color = RGB(58, 56, 56)
    End If
```

K27:K31, K is the last column of my pivot and 27-31 is the row length my pivot will go. Yes, later I will also do something like A31:K31 just in case it shrinks as well.